# Exclude Twitter username in Yahoo Pipes

Tags: regex, twitter, yahoo-pipes, tweets

I'd like to automatically tweet a tweet from one user account based on a keyword from another twitter account.  For example, here's what I currently have set up in Pipes:

Using Fetch Site Feed - http://twitter.com/homesincypress

Filter - Permit items that match ANY of the following...

```
item.title > Contains #bridgelands
item.title > Contains #bridgeland
item.title > Contains bridgeland
item.title > Contains bridgelands
```

Filter - Block items that match ANY of the following...

```
item.title > Matches regex - RT.*RT
```

Output to another Twitter account by grabbing RSS from Pipes output, and using TwitterFeed to update the other Twitter account with those rules.

Tweet looks like this - "**HomesinCypress**: Bridgelands Around the World in 80 sips. Wine Tasting and Model Home tour. Sept. 8 4-7, 19006 Cove Springs, Cypress 281-543-4947."

So, here's what I'm trying to figure out how to do...

**How do I construct the rule in Pipes to where *HomesinCypress:* is excluded from the tweets?**

Comment: it would be a good idea to link to your pipe

Answer (score 0):

Use regex module as below.

In item.title (or whatever it is) replace **^.*?:\s?** with **<blank>**

This way you can modify any other tweeter feed, not just one of HomesinCypress